# Random Sampling without Replacement in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, random

Is there some function in ruby that generates k random numbers in a range without replacement (repetition)?

Something like the random.sample function in Python as shown below

```
>>> import random
>>> random.sample(range(1, 100), 3)
[77, 52, 45]
```

Comment: FWIW: There's [Array::sample](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-sample).

Comment: @orde This is correct. Please make this a full-blown answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a range, convert the range to an array, and then call [Array::sample](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-sample), which can take an argument that specifies the number of samples.

```
(1..100).to_a.sample(3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use this:

```
(1..100).to_a.shuffle[0..2]  #=> [13, 36, 88]
```

Where:

- `(1..100).to_a` creates an array with the possible values.
- `.shuffle` sorts the array randomly.
- `[0..2]` grabs the first 3 elements of shuffled array.